# String.trim only remove the white space on the begin when there are at both ends in Chrome 39 & Firefox

Tags: javascript, string

According to [String.Trim](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/Trim), trim() will remove all the whitespace at both ends, but I tried on Chrome 39 and Firefox 35, `" abc  ".trim()` outputs `"abc  "`, not `"abc"`. Is that a bug?

While IE11 handles that correctly.

Comment: Are you sure you used `trim` and not `trimLeft`? Did you hijack `String.prototype.trim` with a custom function?

Comment: I am unable to reproduce on Chrome 39, `"  abc   ".trim()` returns `"abc"` as expected.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In chrome try debug the String.prototype.trim function, if it goes into a custom function , this may be override.